# find word in sentence and arrange in sequence

Tags: python, string

I have a dict

```
san francisco : city
New york : city
australia : country
```

and query

```
Population of australia is 10 million and it's not in New york
```

Now from query I want to extract keyword from dict. But in same order they appear in query.
Expected output

```
[(australia, country), (new york, city)]
```

Is there any pythonic way to do it.

The way I can think of is to find word from

```
result = []
ind = []
for d in dict:
    if d in query:
        result.append((d, dict[t]))
        ind.append(q.index(d))
r = zip(result,ind)
sol = r.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
result = [i[0] for i in sol]
```

But this is too much of work also look inefficient to me. Please suggest me something better.

Comment: Construct a regex from the keys of the dictionary. Use regex matching to extract the patterns in order of occurrence. Then do dict lookups to extract the values.

Comment: @TimurShtatland how can I handle sequence using regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this using dict comprehension. Be sure to lowercase your text and your dict items.

```
import re

d={'san francisco' : 'city',
'new york' : 'city',
'australia' : 'country'}

keys=list(d.keys())
keys.reverse()

text="Population of new york is 10 million and it's not in australian, san francisco"
regex=re.compile("|".join(["\\b"+i+"\\b" for i in keys]), flags=re.IGNORECASE)


[(i,d[i]) for i in re.findall(re.compile(regex),text)]


[('new york', 'city'), ('san francisco', 'city')]
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But it does not maintain position. e.g `australia and new york` output will be `[('new york', 'city'), ('australia', 'country')]` whereas it should be `[('australia', 'country'), ('new york', 'city')]`

Comment: Also it does not handle cases like `australian bowler are good`. It will output `[australia: country]`

Comment: I fixed all the issues in the updated code